# Is it true that the value of '$x$' and '$y$' which satisfies $a_{1}(x)+b_{1}(y)+c_{1}=0$ will also satisfy $a_{2}(x)+b_{2}(y)+c_{2}=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

consider the following system of equation,

$a_{1}(x)+b_{1}(y)+c_{1}=0$...........(i)

$a_{2}(x)+b_{2}(y)+c_{2}=0$...........(ii)

Now,suppose the values $x=x_{1}$ and $y=y_{1}$ satisfy (i).

So,is it necessary that the same values of x(x1) and y(y1) will also satisfy (ii)? (I do not know what the answer is)

But,i think the author of my book says that yes, the values of x and y for (i) will be same for (ii) also.

(https://postimg.org/image/s3iwkky15/)

He simply assumes that the value of x and y in both (i) & (ii) are same(x1 and y1) and thus he can do subtraction between them.(he subtract a2b1x from a1b2x,b1b2y from b1b2y)

Think of the question like this,some one gives you the following system of equation,

2x+2y+6=0...........(i)

and,2x+3y+11=0....(ii)

Thus,you take a value of x and y which satisfies (i),here x=-1 and y=-2 will satisfy first equation.

And,now you can assume that the same value of x(which is -1) and y(which is -2) will also satisfy the second equation(ii),2x+3y+11=0.

But,when you put x=-1 and y=-2 in the second equation you get this,

2(-1)+3(-2)+11=0

=>(-1)+(-6)+11=0

hence,4=0 [THIS IS WRONG]

so,don't you think, the author **should not have blindly assumed that A value of 'x' and 'y' which would satisfy equation (i) would also satisfy the solution of equation (ii)**?

please help me clear this big confusion!
I am struggling a lot to clear this confusion.
I will be thankful for help!

NOTE:English is not my first language.I am a HIGH SCHOOL student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So,is it necessary that the same values of $x$ ($x_1$) and $y$($y_1$) will also satisfy (ii)? (I do not know what the answer is)

The answer is no. For exmaple, if $a_1=1, b_1=-1, c_1=0, a_2=1, b_2=1,c_2=0$, then the values $x=1, y=1$ satisfy the equation

$$a_1 x+b_1y + c_1=0$$

but they **do not** satisfy the equation $$a_2x+b_2y+c=0$$

---

However, note that the book you posted **does not say** what you think it says. The book is interested in finding the pair $x,y$ that satisfies **BOTH** equations. It doesn't say "if it satisfies the first equation, then it satisfies the second one".

Instead, the author says "let's try to discover which pair $(x,y)$ satisfies both equations". And because the single pair must satisfy *both* equations, it is possible to subtract the two equations.

Comment: Great sir!This is what i was looking for. You know i have wasted many hours thinking about it. I do not know how to thank you for this help! Sir,i need a bit more help,Do you think that it would be correct to make such assumptions ? I mean the author was proving the theorem that if a1/a2=/=b1/b2 then the system of equation has only one solution BUT he assumes first that the given system of equation has a solution which will satisy both the equations.Do you think he was right in doing so?

Comment: @user419155 Happy to help. But please, don't call me sir.

Answer (score 0):

If you visualize in geometric terms it will be much easier.
The two equations you have given can be plotted as straight lines on Cartesian axis. which means infinite number of $(x,y)$ satify each equation individually but, there is only on point where the two lines intersect and give a unique solution to both the equations.

[image]

Unique solution :$(x_1,y_1)= (2,-5)$

Now to calculate this answer you can replace  x and y in both equations by $x_1,y_1$ and then subtract them to get that particular solution.